# JQuery Ajax Data loaded in modal only once

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013

I have the following ajax which when run changes the contents of the div inside my modal body. This works when run the first time, but if the model is closed and then new data is is used when the modal is reloaded. It still displays the previous data-set, How can I clear the modal contents on close, so when the ajax runs it can populate the modal.

HTML

```
<div id="existingrequesthover" class="col-xs-11 outer colorhover" style="border:0px solid">
<div class="vcenter">
    <form id="getDataForm" action="/Home/Index" method="get" role="form">
        <label for="platform" class="control-label">Enter Code, IMEI or Phone Number</label><br />
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-offset-1">
            <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode"></i>
                <input style="max-width:450px;" id="filtername" name="filtername" type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Please Enter Code" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="Enter Code, IMEI or Phone Number" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$("#btnGetData").on("click",function () {
    console.log("Click Detected")
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/AjaxGetDataForCode",
        data: $('#getDataForm').serialize(),
        datatype: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Succes!");
            var $detailDiv = $('#superdatadivthing');
            $detailDiv.replaceWith(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Error!");
        },
        complete: function () {

            $('#basicModal2').modal('show');
            console.log("Complete Ajax!");
        }
    });
});
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-center5">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button id="btnclosemodal" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><p style="font-size: 40px;">&times;</p></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Summary:</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="superdatadivthing">
                <!--data goes here-->
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="resultsgo">Go!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Can anyone suggest a method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is its propably because your selector `$('#superdatadivthing');` doesnt match anything after you overwrite that div with `$detailDiv.replaceWith(data);`

I dont know what `data` is so I can't be sure, but I'd do

`$('#superdatadivthing').html(data);`

and change `data` so it has only the inner html

or add `$detailDiv[0].id = 'superdatadivthing';` after the replace

or include the same id you have in selector to the script which outputs that data

Comment: $('#superdatadivthing').html(data); Worked perfectly, Thanks!